# Numpy , Quoted float array to float array

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

This might be a rookie mistake

but currently, I am trying to convert a float array with is quoted to an actual float array

I am getting data like `"[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]"` which I am trying to convert to `[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0]`

I tried this `np.asarray(quotedArray,dtype=np.float64)`

but its failing with error message ValueError: could not convert string to float: `"[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `json` package, and its `loads()` function to do so:

```
>>> import json
>>> a = '[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]'
>>> a
'[1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]'
>>> b = json.loads(a)
>>> b
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `eval()` even though this can sometimes give unwanted behaviour, so if you can, you should avoid quoted lists to begin with.

```
a = '[1.2, 2, 3.4, 5]'
a = eval(a) # a = [1.2, 2, 3.4, 5], type(a) = <class 'list'>
```

If you want to play around with `eval()` it can be used to take in variable names and function names as strings as well.